# DialogFlow V2 How set fulfillmentText via node js library?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Following this guide:

https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/

I created an action for DialogFlow

```
import { dialogflow, Image, Conversation, BasicCard } from 'actions-on-google';
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('test', (conv, input) => {
    conv.contexts.set('i_see_context_in_web_demo', 1);
    conv.ask(`i see this only into actions on google simulator`);
    conv.ask(new Image({
url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
alt: 'cat',
    }));
});
```

[I then activated Web Demo integration](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/web-demo)

I saw that the Web Demo integration does not show the cards, the images. I hypothesize that it only shows text, no rich text

I understand that it elaborates only JSON like this:

{
   "fulfillmentText": "Welcome!",
   "outputContexts": []
}

But I did not find any method in the library used to enhance fulfillmentText

can you help me?

Comment: Web Demo is not supporting rich messages. 
can you explain what you want to achive /

Comment: I want to reply with the text: hello

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [actions-on-google library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs), which is specifically designed to send messages that will be used by the Google Assistant. The Web Demo uses the generic messages that are available for Dialogflow. The actions-on-google library does not send these generic messages.

If you want to be able to create messages that are usable by both, you'll need to look into the [dialogflow fulfillment library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs), which can create messages that are usable by the Google Assistant as well as other platforms. Be aware, however, that not all rich messages are available on all platforms, but that the basic text responses should be.

You also don't need to use a library - you can create the [JSON response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response) yourself.

Comment: Thank you, but i cannot use that library with express

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818512/how-use-dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs-with-express

Comment: You're welcome, but you certainly can't use the actions-on-google library with the Web Demo. Updated my answer to also discuss doing JSON yourself. Hopefully we can also address your issues with express and the dialogflow-fulfillment library in your other question.