# How use dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs with Express

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es

I want use dialogflow fulfillment library into Express

This is my code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as dialogflowController from './controllers/dialogflow';

const app: express.Application = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/echo', dialogflowController.doActions);
const http = require('http');
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(80, function () { // ascolta sulla porta 80 per comando: ngrok http 80
  console.log('HTTP Started!');
});



// dialogflowController controller unit

import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
const { WebhookClient, Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


export let doActions = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('here it works');
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ req, res });
  console.log('crashes to the previous line');
};
```

And this is the error

```
Error: Request can NOT be empty.
[Node]     at new WebhookClient (D:\Progetti\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js:58:13)
[Node]     at exports.doActions (D:\Progetti\dist\controllers\dialogflow.js:14:19)
[Node]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Progetti\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Can you help me?
How can I use the dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs library with Express?

Comment: You need to use body-parser. Look at this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406463/dialogflow-fulfillment-library-and-express-what-to-res-on

Answer (score 10):

The `WebhookClient` constructor takes an option object with fields `request` and `response`. You named them `req` and `res`.

The constructor line should look something like this given the parameters you have to `doActions()`:

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({
  request: req,
  response: res
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Dude. This is what I'm looking for